# A connection to the remote access server was not made because the modem was not found

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

I'm trying to setup VPN connection and getting this error:

```
Connection failed with error 797
A connection to the remote access server was not made because the modem was not found.
```

Ideas?

UPD I'm not using any 3rd party programs. Only Windows built-in VPN functionality.

Comment: You'll have to explain your setup in FAR more detail in order to get any infomed answer or response to your question.  You'll also have to identify the programs used, error log information, what you have done to debug it too.

Comment: @mdpc, I'm not using any programs or special setup. Only Windows built-in VPN functionality.

Comment: This is a modem error code. Are you connecting through a modem? Do you have a modem on your computer?

Comment: @harrymc, I don't have any modems, only Wi-Fi and some VM virtual networks. And I wasn't asked to choose any modems during VPN setup.

Comment: Had same issue with Windows 7 and a VPN connexion. Fixed thanks to this page : http://www.sorcim.com/knowledgebase/error-797-in-windows-7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is very wrong. Perhaps some more information of what you are doing might help.
Otherwise, the only advice I can give is :

- Try to fully patch Windows by using Windows Update, including all
  optional updates (except bing)
- See if Device Manage has an entry for Modems; if yes, delete it and reboot
- Find out your network adapter manufacture and search for firmware update
- Update the firmware of your router
- Check system integrity via [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

If nothing works, the next step is a [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)
to fix Windows while preserving your user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.